# How to center plots in matplotlib and put a photo in it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've two frames as you can see on the picture. I want to automatically center this two figures and put in a photo. But I failed in the first part. My code is:

```
fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)

# Axes 1

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0))
#ax1.set_title[['[0,0]']

# Axes 2

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 2))
```

I've two other plots, but they don't have to be considered. How to I center this according the whole fig? I couldn't find anything on the matplot site.

Thanks.

[image: Matplotlib]

Comment: Have you considered using [*plt.subplot*](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) for ax1 and ax2 or the whole figure?

Comment: I tried to do it from the first line, but I couldn't figure it out. So i found subplot2grid. But I think I'm not on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want the ratio of the displayed length of x- and y-axes of the subplots in the first row of the figure to change, we can use [`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) to get the expected result by creating a finer resolution of row by having more columns accessible to plot a particular subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)

# Creates a 3 * 13 grid on the figure
ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 13, (4, 6))
ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 13, (8, 10))

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]